# C# - How can I insure a static method effects its parameters directly and not just instances?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 static methods, and only one does what I want it to do, and I can't figure out what's wrong with the other.
More specifically, Method_A seems to not make an instance of its parameter and operates on the same variable that was created in main, whereas B appears to operate on an instance.

```
public static Method_A(Vector2[] in, int n)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < in.Length; i++)
     {
          in[i].x = n;
          in[i].y = n;
     }
}

public static Method_B(Vector2 in, int n)
{
     in.x = n;
     in.y = n;
}
```

And then from main:

```
// This works, and changes values directly in "test"
Vector2[] test = meshFilter.uv;
Method_A(test, n);
meshFilter.uv = test;

// This FAILS, doesn't affect test
Vector2 test = meshFilter.uv[i];
Method_B(test, n);
meshFilter.uv[i] = test;

// This also FAILS, doesn't affect test
Vector2[] t = meshFilter.uv
(...for loop...){
Vector2 test = t[i];
Method_B(test, n);
t[i] = test;}
meshFilter.uv = t;
```

I would like for method B to work on the original variable, not on some instance... What can I do to ensure this?

Please let me know if additional details are required.

Thank you.

Comment: Could `Vector` be a `struct`, and hence passed by value?

Comment: Do you understand what the difference is between a reference type and a value type in C#?

Comment: AlexD Yes, all Vector# are structs. Eric Lippert I can't say I for certain I do... Reading up on this topic now!

Comment: [`Vector2`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) is a structure--a value type--which means it's designed to work by passing a copy of the value instead of a reference when you use it as a parameter. There are of course ways around this (see [`ref` parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)), but this probably isn't going to be as simple as it sounds. You're probably better off designing your application thinking of `Vector2`'s as *values* rather than objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how value types work in C#. If you want to operate on the original struct, you need to pass it by reference.

```
public static Method_B(ref Vector2 in, int n)
{
    in.x = n;
    in.y = n;
}
```

Also, you need to specify that it's been passed by reference at the call site.

```
Method_B(ref test, n);
```

This is not needed for your array, because arrays are reference types. They are passed by reference [1], so your `Method_A` is working on the original array.

[1] To be pedantic, array variables (e.g. `Vector2[] arr` is an array variable) are actually references to arrays. The value of `arr` is passed by value by default, and since this is a reference to an array, this has the effect of passing the array by reference.

Comment: Ok super, I'm going to try that right away. And so why does it work in method A? Does the use of an array remove this need for the "ref" indication? /e Well it works! I wish I knew about this notation before I started my project, this will certainly lighten the code in many places! Marking as answered ASAP! thanks A LOT

Comment: @Werner: Arrays are not value types, they are reference types. They roughly have this property already (note that assigning to the overall value such as `in = new [] {}` works differently)

Comment: An array is an object. Value types in C# are structs (like `DateTime`), enums and basic types like `int`, `char` etc (but not `string`). Strictly speaking everything is passed by value by default in C#, but object variables like the `Vector2[]` in method A are pointers. When method A is invoked, a new pointer to the `Vector2[]` object is created. So if you alter the object, the object in calling code will be altered. But if you set it to a `new Vector2[]` it won't be. If you pass it `ref` then the original pointer is used and the calling code will be passed back the new `Vector2[]`.